# AWK command to multiple all columns of first two rows

Tags: awk

I have a file with many columns and three rows. I am trying to multiply the only first two rows (all of the columns in these rows) by -1 to flip their signs. New to coding so bear with me please, I've been googling around for a while now and I'm still confused.

So far what I have:

```
awk 'NR==1 {print $0*-1} NR==2 {print $0*-1}' filename
```

Any guidance is much appreciated. Here's a sample of the data...

```
0 0.6548 0.2719 -0.7817, etc
0 -0.355659 -0.933965 -0.152743 -0.110437, etc 
0 0.666817 0.231877 -0.179657 0.986756 -0.127037 0.377155, etc (3 rows, about 50 columns)
```

Comment: How are the columns separated? Also which column i.e the third, are you looking to multiply? An example of your data would be great

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk 'NR < 3 { for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) { $i=$i*-1 } }1' > filename.tmp && cp -f filename.tmp filename && rm -f filename.tmp
```

Where the number record is less than third, loop from 1 to number of fields (NF) setting the field ($i) equal to the field * -1. Use short hand 1 to print the line

I've assumed a space for the delimiter. Change accordingly if necessary with awk -F

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked! Now, how would I go about saving these changes to the file?

Comment: I've amended the solution to output to a temp file, copy to the original and remove the temp file.